# Link not working in ReactJS without hitting enter in address bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is how I defined the Router, Route, Switch:

```
 <div>
  <Router>
    <Navbar onShowSideNav={this.onShowSideNav}/>
     {this.state.show && <SideNav/>}
      <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
       <Route path="/search" component={Searches}/>
        <Route path="/message" component={Messages}/>
      </Switch>
  </Router>
 </div>
```

and this is how I defined Link:

```
<ul className="text-center ulside">
   
     <Link to="/" className="aside">
       <li className="liside">Home</li>
     </Link>

     <Link to="/search" className="aside">
        <li className="liside">search</li>
     </Link>
     <Link to="/payam" className="aside">
     <li className="liside">message</li>
     </Link>
 </ul>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and is not displayed in the address bar after hitting Enter!
I use django for backends and urls is correctly true!
how can i solve this problem?

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You probably want BrowserRouter instead of Router.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: router means BrowserRouter. i use BrowserRouter as Router

Answer (score 0):

Your route is not correctly define at the link component.

Home

```
 <Link to="/search" className="aside">
    <li className="liside">search</li>
 </Link>

 <Link to="/message" className="aside">
    <li className="liside">message</li>
 </Link>
```

Comment: that is my project url but i didn't change second time . however i change that at first time,